# SQL Select Items and link field to another table in same select

Tags: sql, select

Currently I am retrieving a list of Purchase Orders Lines (POL) and each has a Due Date. For each line where the POL.Due Date is a future date i.e. >= Current Date, I need to determine the Period Name and Financial Week the POL.Due Date falls into.

The SQL Database has a table for the Financial Period and one for the Financial Week. Each table is driven by a date.

```
PERIODPER
    PERIOD_DATE
    PERIOD
    PERIOD_NAME
    PERIOD_YEAR

PERIOD_WEEK
    START_DATE
    WEEK
    YEAR
```

Against each report line along with the Due Date I am trying to link to each of the above tables to determine the PERIOD_NAME and WEEK for the POL.Due Date.

Where the POL.Due Date has elapsed i.e. < Current Date, I need to retrieve the PERIOD_NAME and WEEK for the Current Date.

I would like to try and do this in an SQL select as my only other option is to write a VBA report which initially retrieves all the Purchase Order Lines and then serially reads through each and links to the other tables to determine the Financial Period Name and Week Number.

I am looking for an end result something on the lines of:

```
PO_NUMBER   PO_LINE   DUE_DATE   WEEK_NO  PERIOD_NAME
```

I would appreciate any assistance on this as my SQL knowledge does not extend to what to me appears to be a complex selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this (SQL Server syntax)?

```
select  pol.po_number,
        pol.po_line,
        pol.due_date,
        pw.week as week_no,
        pp.period_name
from    purchaseOrderLines pol
        left join period_week pw    on pol.DueDate > GetDate()
                                    and pw.start_date <= pol.due_date
                                    and dateAdd(d, 7, pw.start_date) >= pol.due_date
        left join periodPer pp  on pol.DueDate > GetDate()
                                and pp.period_date = pol.DueDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response.

I tried your logic which gave me what I was looking for but upon further investigation I located another table which detailed every date up to 2025, including the week and month. I'm simply now creating a JOIN to this new table using my Due Date value.

I would just like to thank you for your time and effort in answering my query. Although I am not using your suggestion for the stated example, I am however looking at what you've presented, and it certainly gives me a few ideas for some other SELECT statements I'm currently working on.